# Can't resolve Illegal characters in path

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I use VS Community 2019.
When I am trying to resolve merge conflict or merge master to local branch, I am getting error message "Illegal characters in path".
I have looked at other messages in stackoverflow and:

1. Removed other GITs
2. Installed GIT for Windows
3. Restarted my computer
4. Updated VS
5. Looked for %localappdata% (but didn't find it)

Any idea? Thanks in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic solution is here :)

0. Close Visual Studio
1. Go to start
2. Type %localappdata%
3. Find this folder /AppData/Local/Microsoft/VisualStudio/16.0 (or another version)
4. Delete ComponentModelCache folder
5. Open Visual Studio

Now should work